# django-taggit delete tables south

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-taggit

I need to delete a table I think django-taggit but as I am no longer occupying the app

http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

To control the database occupy south, I've searched the documentation but to no avail.

```
python manage.py migrate --list:
.....
    taggit
    (*) 0001_initial
    (*) 0002_unique_tagnames
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the migrations are written to be able to go backward, you can use following command:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp zero
```